# NestedRecyclerview layout is loading but the data is not being populated firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

if anyone know the solution please help me out!!
i am trying to create a nested recyclerview in kotlin the layout is being displayed but the data is not being populated in the layout
This is the my model classes[Kotlin]
this is the sub item class ->

```
data class AppointConstructor ( var id : String ?= null,
                            var name : String ?= null,
                            var mobile : String ?= null,
                            var profilePic : String ?= null,
                            var Time : String ?= null,
                       var date : String ?= null)
```

this is  the parent  model ->

```
data class ParentOnlyDate(  var date : String ?= null,
                  var data : List<AppointConstructor> ?= null)
```

[Check my firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDchT.png)

These are the adapters i am using
subItem Adapter

```
class SubItemAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SubItemAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

private var list : ArrayList<AppointConstructor> = ArrayList<AppointConstructor>()
var fragment : Fragment = Fragment()

class MyViewHolder(view : DoctorHistoryItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root){
    val image = view.historyImage
    val name = view.HistoryName
    val call = view.HistoryCall
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val binding : DoctorHistoryItemBinding = DoctorHistoryItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
   val appointModel : AppointConstructor = list[position]
    holder.name.text = appointModel.name

    holder.call.setOnClickListener {
        if(fragment is DoctorHistory){
            val number : String = appointModel.mobile.toString()
            (fragment as DoctorHistory).callUser(number)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
fun appointmentList(historyList: ArrayList<AppointConstructor>){
    this.list = historyList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun passingFragment(frag : Fragment){
    fragment = frag
}
```

}

This is my parent adapter ->

```
class ParentAdapter(fragment : Fragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

var list : ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate> = ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate>()

public class MyViewHolder(view : RecyclerviewsubitemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root){
     val titleDate : TextView = view.TitleTextview
     val recyclerView : RecyclerView = view.SubRecyclerViewId
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val binding : RecyclerviewsubitemBinding = RecyclerviewsubitemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val pd : ParentOnlyDate = list[position]
    holder.titleDate.text = pd.date
    holder.recyclerView.hasFixedSize()
    holder.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context)
    val childAdapter : HistoryAdapter = HistoryAdapter()
    pd.data?.let { childAdapter.appointmentList(it as ArrayList<AppointConstructor>) }
    holder.recyclerView.adapter = childAdapter
    childAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

fun setParentItem(list : ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate>){
    this.list = list
}
```

}

Now this is my Livedataviewmodel

```
private val parentAdapterList : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate>> by lazy {

    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate>>().also {

        val ref = firebaseDatabase.child("Doctor").child(auth).child("History")
       ref.get().addOnSuccessListener {
           val completeItems : ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate> = arrayListOf()
           if(it.exists()){
               val items : ParentOnlyDate? = it.getValue(ParentOnlyDate::class.java)
               for (obj in it.children){
                   if (items != null) {
                       completeItems.add(items)
                     
                   }else{
                       println("Items are Null..")
                   }
               }

               if(completeItems.isNotEmpty() || completeItems.size > 0){
                   parentAdapterList.value = completeItems
               }else{
                   completeItems.clear()
                   parentAdapterList.value = completeItems
               }

           }else{
               println("Snapshot doesn't Exist")
           }
       }
    }
}

fun getParentSubItems() : LiveData<ArrayList<ParentOnlyDate>>{
    return parentAdapterList
}
```

when i try to print the size of the list to check if the list exists i am getting the right size of the list

this is my fragment code where i want to display the nested fragment

```
    val model : HistoryViewModel by viewModels()

    val childAdapter = HistoryAdapter()

    val adapter = ParentAdapter(this@DoctorHistory)

    childAdapter.passingFragment(this@DoctorHistory)

    model.getParentSubItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            data ->
        run {
            data.let {
                when(it){
                    it ->{
                        if(it.isNotEmpty() || it.size > 0){
                            adapter.setParentItem(it)
                        }
                        if (it.isEmpty() || it.size == 0){
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val layoutManager : LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        _binding?.RecyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        _binding?.RecyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        _binding?.RecyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
```

The layout is being shown but the data is not being displayed

[This is being shown in the build.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLmMM.png)

it is showing layout but the data is not being populated please help me with this , Thank you.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Hello Sir, @AlexMamo sir i've edited the code with only important data please take a look at it, Thank you.